# Can I return a card from the graveyard that is active?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say that I have a [Salvager of Ruin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSalvager%20of%20Ruin%5d) and [Deliver Unto Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeliver%20Unto%20Evil%5d) and then I activated Deliver Unto Evil then use Salvager of Ruin to return it before it fully activates and if yes can I use this to return a card activating that exiles it at the end of the activation?

Comment: You mentioned "Druess" but there's no such card; there *is* a card called [Duress](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=466851) but it does something unrelated to the question at hand (I think). Given the images, I've assumed you meant Deliver Unto Evil.

Comment: Be careful not to use the term "activated" in this situation when what you mean is "cast". MTG is very specific with its language, and activating an ability is different than casting a spell.

Comment: @GendoIkari And there is a reason for MTG insistence on specific language.  "Can I return a spell from the graveyard while it is on the stack?" seems like an question most people should be able to answer.

Comment: @Taemyr If it were a permanent that was sacrificed as part of the cost of activating an ability, then it would be in the graveyard before that ability resolved and could be returned from the graveyard while the ability was still "active" on the stack. Wording does matter when using words that may be correct in general English but have specific definitions in game that you don't mean. Stack Exchange isn't just to answer the question for the asker.

Answer (score 9):

No, that doesn't work for no less than three reasons:

- First of all, Deliver Unto Evil is a sorcery, while Salvager of Ruin's ability refers to permanents.
- Secondly, Deliver Unto Evil resolves while it is on the stack, and is only put into a graveyard after it full resolves. But before that happens, it exiles itself, so it never reaches your graveyard.
- Thirdly, you can't activate abilities while a spell is resolving (mana abilities are an exception in certain cases).

Answer (score 1):

Just to go further into details of what Glorfindel explained.

When you cast [Deliver Unto Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeliver%20Unto%20Evil%5d), you put the spell on the stack. This card will remain on the stack until it fully resolves. This is not an "activated spell", the spell is simply cast and put on the stack.
The last phrase on the spell:

> Exile [Deliver Unto Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeliver%20Unto%20Evil%5d).

This is not a replacement effect, usually you will see wordings of "instead of placing it on the graveyard, exile it instead", this leaves room for things that alter the replacement effects to your advantage, in this case [Deliver Unto Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeliver%20Unto%20Evil%5d) exiles itself, takes itself to the exile zone, which means that at the point where the game would try to place the card to your graveyard, it already is in the exile zone instead.

Now as explained in other answers, this spell is a sorcery and not a permanent therefore you could not bring it back to your hand with [Salvager of Ruin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSalvager%20of%20Ruin%5d).

Even if you attempt to return a permanent put in the graveyard with [Deliver Unto Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeliver%20Unto%20Evil%5d), this would not work as this is the wording:

> Sacrifice Salvager of Ruin: Choose target permanent card in your
>   graveyard that was put there from the battlefield this turn. Return it
>   to your hand.

The cards that ended up in the graveyard, didn't come from the battlefield, they would have been the result of [Deliver Unto Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeliver%20Unto%20Evil%5d), entering the graveyard directly from the library.